# Plausibility of directly modifying a binary executable without corrupting it

Tags: python, c, security

Firstly, just in case anybody is wondering, this question is for *educational* purposes only.

Say that I've been given a binary executable file (complied from C code). This binary executable takes a single argument, a password, and it writes out a secret message if the password is correct. In practice `$./jeff-binary jeffspassword` would yield `Secret: Jeff's Secret Message`

I wish to know that secret while circumnavigating the necessity to know the password (`jeffspassword`). I know that in the C code which created these binaries, the path which contains the password is hard-coded in. There will be a part in the code which reads: `fp = fopen("/etc/secret-password-dir/jeff/password", "r");` Obviously, since I'm not Jeff, I do not have permission to either read or write to `jeff`.

Since I have access to this binary, what I've done currently is read in the binary file as a single, long hex string, then searched it for the hex string matching (as per the example) `/etc/secret-password-dir/jeff/password` and replacing it with `/home/fred/Documents/blank_password`, then created a new binary which has this single change. The intention is that the file pointer will end up assuming the password is whatever I put into `blank_password` (which I know), and therefore I can run this modified binary with a non-password so it prints out Jeff's secret.

Specifically, the process which I currently have running is this:

1. I have a C program which reads in the contents of `jeff-binary` and writes it as hex string to `hex_of_jeff_binary.txt`.
2. I then have a Python script which reads `hex_of_jeff_binary.txt` does some string comprehension by replacing the hex representation of `/etc/secret-password-dir/jeff/password` with `/home/fred/Documents/blank_password`, then writes this modified binary as `jeff-binary-mod`.
3. `chmod +x jeff-binary-mod` to make it executable.
4. The result is: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. Eh.

My questions are: is what I'm attempting to do possible? If so, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Where in the code is it crashing? Or do you not have access to the C code?

Comment: (1) Compare `jeff-binary` with `jeff-binary-mode` byte-for-byte to see if there are any differences other than the intended change to the string. You may find the `od -xa` command useful to display a file using hex and ASCII characters—you can display each file with `od -xa` and then compare the two outputs of `od`. (2) If you do not have permission to open etc/secret-password-dir/jeff/password, why would you expect an executable file you wrote to have such permission? The original executable might have that permission if it is marked setuid and is owned by Jeff. But your copy will not.

Comment: did you replace the original string with a string of the same length ? If not, you changed the size of the binary file, and more importantly, you invalidated all offsets after the change.

Comment: In general, "patching" executable binary files is extremely difficult, so difficult it might as well be impossible for most purposes.  But the exception is string constants, such as the pathname you're trying to alter.  It's perfectly straightforward to alter those, *if* you don't alter their length.  If the new string is the same length as, or shorter than, the old, you're fine.  If the new string is longer than the old, you can't do it, unless you're lucky and the data just beyond the string somehow isn't important.  (Also remember to preserve the null termination.)

Comment: Following up on the comment by @EricPostpischil, another extremely useful tool (on Unix-like systems) is `cmp -l`.  You can use if to both verify that you changed the string you expected to, and that the offset/position of everything following that string didn't change.

Comment: Modify your Python script so that it only reads and writes the file without replacing anything and then see if the new binary works or not. If it doesn't work, then the problem is most likely within the Python script.

Comment: Why the detour into a "hex string"?

Comment: @steve: patching a literal string like that can have unintended consequences if the compiler has optimized storage by overlaying string literals, which it can do if one literal is a suffix of the other one.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce what OP intends to achieve (as far as I understood it).

1. I wrote a little password "safed" application in C.

`testSecret.c`:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  const char *password = "MySecretPassword";
  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR! Wrong number of command line arguments.\n");
    return -1;
  }
  if (strcmp(argv[1], password) == 0) {
    printf("Hello, proper receiver of secret message.\n");
  } else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Nice try but FAILED!\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled and tested in [cygwin64](http://www.cygwin.org) on Windows 10:

```
$ gcc -std=c11 -o testSecret testSecret.c

$ ./testSecret 
ERROR! Wrong number of command line arguments.

$ ./testSecret wrong
Nice try but FAILED!

$ ./testSecret MySecretPassword
Hello, proper receiver of secret message.

$
```

2. I loaded the binary into the [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) with Hex-Editor plug-in. I look for the initialization text of `password`.

[image: snapshot of Notepad++ with found string constant]

3. The first byte of constant string is overwritten with 0. (It's important that no byte is inserted nor erased. Otherwise, all addresses of following will become wrong and binary will be surely broken.) The "patched" file is saved as `testSecretCracked.exe`.

[image: snapshot of Notepad++ after patching and saving the binary]

4. Test the cracked binary:

```
$ ./testSecretCracked.exe 
ERROR! Wrong number of command line arguments.

$ ./testSecretCracked.exe ""
Hello, proper receiver of secret message.

$
```

The new password after cracking is now `""`. So, the secret reduces to the experience to pass an argument with empty string on `bash`.

---

Of course, this is a demo for entertainment / educational purpose only. There are many reasons while this may fail (e.g. the one mentioned in comments). Commercial applications might contain encrypted data (which are decrypted at runtime). A simple check might be to hash internal data and compare it with a hash code which would de-mask most of modifications. (Btw. *our* commercial applications are shipped with a H/W license check which combines the above safety techniques with others.)

---

Just for fun, I automated the simple "cracking" as describe above:

`testAutoCrack.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if (argc != 4) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR! Wrong number of command line arguments.\n");
    return -1;
  }
  const char *inFile = argv[1];
  const char *outFile = argv[2];
  const char *password = argv[3];
  /* read binary */
  size_t size = 0x1000;
  char *buffer = malloc(size);
  if (!buffer) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR! Out of memory.\n");
    return -1;
  }
  FILE *fIn = fopen(inFile, "rb");
  if (!fIn) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR! Failed to open '%s'.\n", inFile);
    return -1;
  }
  size_t lenTotal = 0;
  for (;;) {
    size_t lenRead = size - lenTotal;
    size_t len = fread(buffer + lenTotal, 1, lenRead, fIn);
    lenTotal += len;
    if (len < lenRead) break; // EOF
    char *bufferNew = realloc(buffer, 2 * size);
    if (!bufferNew) {
      fprintf(stderr, "ERROR! Out of memory.\n");
      return -1;
    }
    buffer = bufferNew;
    size *= 2;
  }
  fclose(fIn);
  /* find password in binary */
  size_t lenPassword = strlen(password) + 1;
  if (lenTotal < lenPassword) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR! Password longer than binary.\n");
    return -1;
  }
  size_t i = lenTotal - lenPassword;
  while (i-- && strncmp(buffer + i, password, lenPassword) != 0);
  if (i >= lenTotal) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Password '%s' not found!\n", password);
    return -1;
  }
  /* patch password */
  buffer[i] = '\0';
  /* write binary */
  FILE *fOut = fopen(outFile, "wb");
  if (!fOut) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR! Failed to open '%s'.\n", outFile);
    return -1;
  }
  if (fwrite(buffer, 1, lenTotal, fOut) < lenTotal
    || fclose(fOut)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR! Failed to write '%s'.\n", outFile);
    return -1;
  }
  /* done */
  printf("'%s' successfully cracked.\n", inFile);
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled and tested:

```
$ gcc -std=c11 -o testAutoCrack testAutoCrack.c 

$ ./testAutoCrack testSecret.exe testSecretAutoCracked.exe MySecretPassword
'testSecret.exe' successfully cracked.

$ chmod a+x testSecretAutoCracked.exe

$ ./testSecretAutoCracked.exe ""
Hello, proper receiver of secret message.

$
```